# Upcase script in titleformat causes TeX capacity exceeded error

Tags: titlesec, shell-escape

I'm trying to get `\titleformat` to use a shell script `upcase`
instead of `\MakeUppercase` to upcase the section title in the
document but not in the table of contents.  (I know `\MakeUppercase`
achieves this, but I want a custom function for a different reason,
namely for stripping Greek of diacritics before upcasing.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\def\call#1{\input{|"#1"}}
\def\upcase#1{\call{upcase #1}}
\titleformat{\section}{}{\thesection.\quad}{0pt}{\upcase}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{banana}

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% engine: luatex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

This works without `\tableofcontents`, but with it I get a `TeX
capacity exceeded` error.  Why?

An upcase script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# upcase
emacsclient -e "(intern (upcase \"$*\"))"
```

Comment: Using `\MakerUppercase` in `\titleformat` doesn't uppercase the section title in the table of contents by default.

Comment: @Bernard, I know, I want a custom function for a different reason.

Comment: At least you need `\@@input|"#1"` rather than `\input{|"#1"}`.

Comment: @egreg, all right, why?  it didn't make a noticeable difference.